# Interpret two dimensional array in Func<double[]>

Tags: c#

I am using Accord math to solve nonlinear function with nonlinear constraints
The problem is that `NonlinearObjectiveFunction` function take argument `function` that is `Func<double[], double> function` in my case it's something like

```
x =>
x[0] * (Matrix[0, 0] * x[0] + Matrix[1, 0] * x[1] + Matrix[2, 0] * x[2]) +
x[1] * (Matrix[0, 1] * x[0] + Matrix[1, 1] * x[1] + Matrix[2, 1] * x[2]) +
x[2] * (Matrix[0, 2] * x[0] + Matrix[1, 2] * x[1] + Matrix[2, 2] * x[2])
```

Is it possible somehow to build this `function` using a cycle? Because dimension of input matrix can change.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[,] Matrix = new double[3, 3];

            Matrix[0, 0] = 0.00234329;
            Matrix[0, 1] = 0.00118878;
            Matrix[0, 2] = 0.00152143;
            Matrix[1, 0] = 0.00118878;
            Matrix[1, 1] = 0.00206312;
            Matrix[1, 2] = 0.00124812;
            Matrix[2, 0] = 0.00152143;
            Matrix[2, 1] = 0.00124812;
            Matrix[2, 2] = 0.00194796;

            double x1 = 0.0107;
            double x2 = -0.00054;
            double x3 = -0.0034;

            var f = new NonlinearObjectiveFunction(3, x =>
            x[0] * (Matrix[0, 0] * x[0] + Matrix[1, 0] * x[1] + Matrix[2, 0] * x[2]) +
            x[1] * (Matrix[0, 1] * x[0] + Matrix[1, 1] * x[1] + Matrix[2, 1] * x[2]) +
            x[2] * (Matrix[0, 2] * x[0] + Matrix[1, 2] * x[1] + Matrix[2, 2] * x[2])
            );

            var constraints = new[]
            {
                new NonlinearConstraint(3, x => x1 * x[0] + x2 * x[1] + x3 * x[2] >= 0.01),
                new NonlinearConstraint(3, x=> x[0] + x[1] + x[2]>=1 ),
                new NonlinearConstraint(3, x=> x[0] + x[1] + x[2]<=1 ),
                new NonlinearConstraint(3, x=> x[0]>=0),
                new NonlinearConstraint(3, x=> x[1]>=0),
                new NonlinearConstraint(3, x=> x[2]>=0)
            };

            var cobyla = new Cobyla(f, constraints);
            bool success = cobyla.Minimize();
            double minimum = cobyla.Value;
            double[] solution = cobyla.Solution;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does "using a cycle" means something special? (Obviously you can write matrix multiplication with loops as many people done in the past... so I assume you need something different - but it is not necessary clear what it is)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lambda expression you show in your code example could be rewritten like this:

```
double ApplyMatrix(double[,] matrix, double[] x)
{
    double sum = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.GetLength(1); row++)
    {
        double rowSum = 0;

        for (int col = 0; col < matrix.GetLength(0); col++)
        {
            rowSum += matrix[col, row] * x[col];
        }

        sum += x[row] * rowSum;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Then, you could pass a lambda expression to the `NonlinearObjectiveFunction` that uses the above:

```
var f = new NonlinearObjectiveFunction(3, x => ApplyMatrix(Matrix, x));
```

This, of course, assumes that the dimensions of your user-defined `Matrix` and of the `x` array passed to your method are consistent with each other. I.e. your user-defined matrix is always square, and the `x` array always has at least as many elements as there are rows and columns in the user-defined matrix.

If that's not what you're asking about, please improve your question by providing a more precise description of what it is you're trying to accomplish, including an explanation of what you mean by *"cycle"*.